# Is there a way to call API A and switch to B if A fails on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, load-balancing, cdn

Is there a way to call API A and switch to B if A fails? We are using AWS.

It is probably difficult to change automatically, but it would be nice to be able to change it manually in the console.

Thank you!

Comment: There are a ton of different ways to achieve high availability on AWS. Which options are best depends on which services you use and your specific requirements.

Comment: "On AWS" is very vague.  AWS is a collection of hundreds of different services.  Is this something you are doing from an EC2 instance or are you using some other AWS service to call this API?